# How to know where is Libreoffice installed in a Docker image?

Tags: linux, docker, libreoffice

I am trying to convert a docx document to PDF by using libreoffice as follows:

```
from subprocess import  Popen
LIBRE_OFFICE = r"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe"

def convert_to_pdf(input_docx, out_folder):
    p = Popen([LIBRE_OFFICE, '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir',
               out_folder, input_docx])
    print([LIBRE_OFFICE, '--convert-to', 'pdf', input_docx])
    p.communicate()


sample_doc = 'file.docx'
out_folder = 'some_folder'
convert_to_pdf(sample_doc, out_folder)
```

However, I am working on a Linux Docker image. So I don't need what route should I specify in the `LIBRE_OFFICE` variable. Does anybody knows it?

The command I am using in my Dockerfile to install libreoffice is `RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libreoffice`

Comment: libreoffice is automatically added to PATH when installed so you don't need the route, you can just do `LIBRE_OFFICE = "libreoffice"`

Answer (score 0):

On linux the `which` command will tell you where an executible is installed. For example on my system

```sh
$ which libreoffice 
/usr/bin/libreoffice
```

You can generally do this for every executable, and also to check IF an executable is installed. This approach will work even if the output of the `which` command is a symbolic link.